# Interop.Word.ApplicationClass.DocumentBeforeSaveEvent doesn't always fire

Tags: c#, ms-word, word-automation

I have a C# Application that Automates MS Word. I want to keep track of the automated documents and certain actions have to happen on close so I've disabled the document close event.

Setting `cancel = true;` works on my workstation, a users Workstation, and a freshly imaged workstation. However it does not work for one of my test users.  If I log in to her PC as a different user it works. Which leads me to believe the problem is some setting she's applied to Word.

How can I get the `DocumentBeforeCloseEvent` to reliably trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this here in case it helps someone else.

I ended up doing a repair on the troublesome P.C. It wasn't an ideal solution but it worked.